# when using fixtures with scope session and class , tests with scope class runs twice

Tags: python, pytest

I have a below py.test program where i need to 2 fixtures, one with scope "session" and other with scope "class", the fixture with scope "class" takes fixture with "session" as one of it's argument.

While running tests that uses scope as "class", the tests seems to run twice,

Below is the code.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def session_fixture(request):
    data = ['hello world']
    return data

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def class_fixture(session_fixture, request):
    if hasattr(request.cls, 'test1'):
        request.cls().test1(session_fixture)
    return session_fixture

class TestClass:
    def test1(self,class_fixture):
        print("Hello World")
```

When i run the test, it seems to print "hello world" twice.

Ouput:

```
$ py.test test7.py -s
=============== test session start============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.27 -- pytest-2.7.0
rootdir: /root/fix2, inifile: 
plugins: multihost
collected 1 items 

test7.py Hello World
Hello World
. 
================ 1 passed in 0.09 seconds ===================
```

In the above program if i use the fixture "session_fixture" directly instead of "class_fixture", i see that "Hello world" is printed only once.

Any hints on how i could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'test' case seems to be incorrect

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def session_fixture(request):
    data = ['hello world']
    print("Session fixture")
    return data

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def class_fixture(session_fixture, request):
    print("Class fixture")
    return session_fixture


class TestClass:
    def test1(self,class_fixture):
        print("Hello World 1")

    def test2(self, class_fixture):
        print('Hello World 2')
```

this gives:

```
py.test test.py -s

collected 2 items 

test.py::TestClass::test1 Session fixture
Class fixture
Hello World 1
PASSED
test.py::TestClass::test2 Hello World 2
PASSED
```

So class-based fixture is executed only once.
Pytest has massive test coverage on simple cases like this to be sure it always works as declared.

Comment: The above works, but if you add the if condition to class_fixture to call this fixture to run on specific function in testclass, then it runs twice.

Comment: this makes no sense to do - pytest has born with dependency injection, just use that, eg only request fixture in the prototype when it's used in the test function